# Updating multiple Cell Values in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset is in this form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4],
                   'Type': ['A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'Value': [100, 200, 201, 120]})
```

I want to update the dataframe in the following way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1,2,3,4],
                   'Type': ['A', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3'],
                   'Value': [100, 200, 201, 120]})
```

The code I was trying was:

```
df[df['Type'] == 'B', df['Value'] == 200] = 'B1'
```

But I'm getting error:

`ValueError: Cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Can someone please help me solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
df.loc[df['Type'].eq('B') & df['Value'].eq(200), 'Type'] = 'B1'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df['Type'] = df['Type'].mask(df['Type'].eq('B'),
                             df['Type'] + df.groupby('Type').cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
                            )
```

Comment: @mozway: Thanks a lot for your answer. It worked perfectly. But U12-Forward answer is correct, he shared first . So, will accept this answer.

Comment: @Beta sure, most important is you got your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

If need convert all `B` values by iterator starting by `1` use `np.arange` by count `True`s by `sum` and join by `+`:

```
m = df['Type'] == 'B'
df.loc[m, 'Type'] += np.arange(1, m.sum()+1).astype(str)
print (df)

   ID Type  Value
0   1    A    100
1   2   B1    200
2   3   B2    201
3   4   B3    120
```

Comment: Your answer worked. But U12-Forward answer is correct & he shared first. So, will accept this answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Beta - If need set by multiple conditions then you are right.

Comment: Thanks! I learned something new from each answer. But unfortunately can accept only 1 answer.

Comment: @Bera No problem, happy coding.